# Slow subquery in MySQL

Tags: mysql

im trying to generate a report using CodeIgniter and Datatables.net .

Now i'm trying to the amount of closed jobs (its a human resources system). I used to query all jobs and in PHP do a foreach and then doing the calcs.

Because im want to use all the features of Datatables (sorting specifically) im trying to do all the calcs in mySQL.

The problem is: the second subquery is very very very slow.

```
SELECT 
jobs.jobs_id, clients.nome_fantasia, concat_ws(' ', user_profiles.first_name, user_profiles.last_name) as fullname, 
jobs.titulo_vaga, jobs.qtd_vagas, company.name as nome_company, jobs_status.name as      status_name, DATEDIFF(NOW(), jobs.data_abertura) as date_idade, 
(select count(job_cv.jobs_id) from job_cv where job_cv.jobs_id = jobs.jobs_id) as qtd_int,
(select count(distinct job_cv.user_id) from job_cv_history join job_cv on job_cv.job_cv_id = job_cv_history.job_cv_id where job_cv_history.status = '11' and job_cv.jobs_id = jobs.jobs_id ) as fechadas 
FROM (jobs)
JOIN clients ON lients.clients_id=jobs.clients_idJOIN user_profiles ON jobs.consultor_id=user_profiles.user_id
JOIN jobs_status ON jobs.status=jobs_status.jobs_status_id 
JOIN company ON jobs.company_id=company.company_id 
LIMIT 50
```

Some one can help me? I can provide more information if its needed.

**UPDATE**

The idea to use JOIN instead SELECT work with the first subquery but with the second one not, there a way to pass a 'variable' to use inside the subquery? Like the current jobs_id?

**UPDATE AGAIN**

This line works fine by itself. But inside the subquery take about a minute with worng values

```
SELECT job_cv.jobs_id,count(distinct job_cv.user_id) AS fechadas
FROM job_cv_history 
JOIN job_cv 
ON job_cv.job_cv_id = job_cv_history.job_cv_id 
WHERE job_cv_history.status = '11'
GROUP BY job_cv.jobs_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not subquery that is slow. It's the fact, that you're executing these subqueries for each row returned from outer query. Move these to joins instead, and you should observe increase in performance.

```
SELECT 
  jobs.jobs_id, clients.nome_fantasia, concat_ws(' ', user_profiles.first_name, user_profiles.last_name) as fullname, 
jobs.titulo_vaga, jobs.qtd_vagas, company.name as nome_company, jobs_status.name as      status_name, DATEDIFF(NOW(), jobs.data_abertura) as date_idade, 
qtd.qtd_int,
fechadas.fechadas 
FROM (jobs)
JOIN clients ON lients.clients_id=jobs.clients_idJOIN user_profiles ON jobs.consultor_id=user_profiles.user_id
JOIN jobs_status ON jobs.status=jobs_status.jobs_status_id 
JOIN company ON jobs.company_id=company.company_id 
JOIN (
  SELECT jobs_id, count(jobs_id) AS qtd_int FROM job_cv GROUP BY jobs_id
) AS qtd ON qtd.jobs_id = jobs.jobs_id
JOIN (
  SELECT job_cv.user_id, count(distinct job_cv.user_id) AS fechadas
  FROM job_cv_history 
  JOIN job_cv 
  ON job_cv.job_cv_id = job_cv_history.job_cv_id 
  WHERE job_cv_history.status = '11'
  GROUP BY job_cv.user_id
) AS fechadas ON job_cv.jobs_id = jobs.jobs_id
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Tkz... i came up with this to work: http://pastebin.com/rzjAW7Sj the firts join qtd is fine... but the second... i get only the total of fechadas... and i need the total for each jobs..any ideias please?

Answer (score 2):

You may try to create these indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `job_cv` ADD INDEX `job_cv_cindex` (`job_cv_id` ASC, `jobs_id` ASC, `user_id` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `job_cv_history` ADD INDEX `job_cv_history_cindex` (`job_cv_id` ASC, `status` ASC);
```

Comment: Just did, same time. Can you explain why the indexes can help?

Answer (score 1):

use Joins instead of sub queries. It significantly improves the performance in MySql.
try to use Left join on your case and see if performance improves or not